# Android Delete app's file after unistall

Tags: android

I noticed that the Android app once uninstalled, leave the folder of the app, but all the files are deleted, my app instead once uninstalled does not delete files it creates, so it is not something that Android does this automatically, so I wanted to know how to delete my files after I uninstalled the app, I tried to check the manifest.xml file, but I have not found anything useful, I've seen bad?

Comment: How are you generating the path to save the files? Android will take care of this for you if you are using the appropriate APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I save my file in this way:

> String sdcard =
> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
> +"/Android/data";
>
> ```
> String Folder= "com.android."+"myAppName";
>  String sdcard_core = sdcard + "/"+Folder+ "/"+"Core";
> File File_1 = new File(sdcard_core, "test.txt");
> File File_2 = new File(sdcard_core, "test2.txt");
> ecc..
> ```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on where you're storing the file. If you're storing the files in the External Storage, Android will not remove these files when the app is being uninstalled. Also, it is impossible to know when your app is being uninstalled so that you could delete these files by yourself.

The other possible way to do this could be to use the [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). Android removes these files when the app is being uninstalled. However, these files are not directly available to other apps or to the user himself.